# Adding active class to parent of current pages url of multilevel menu

Tags: jquery

I have a multilevel menu

```
<ul class="st_mega_menu clearfix mu_level_0">
   <li id="st_menu_16" class="ml_level_0 m_alignment_0">
      <a id="st_ma_16" href="javascript:void(0);" class="ma_level_0 is_parent" title="SHOP FLOORING">SHOP FLOORING</a>
      <ul id="st_menu_multi_level_16" class="stmenu_sub stmenu_multi_level">
         <li class="ml_level_1">
            <a id="st_ma_17" href="https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca/wood-flooring.html" ><i class="fto-angle-right list_arrow"></i>Wood Flooring<span class="is_parent_icon"><b class="is_parent_icon_h"></b><b class="is_parent_icon_v"></b></span></a>        
            <ul class="mu_level_2 p_granditem_1">
               <li class="ml_level_2 granditem_0 p_granditem_1">
                  <a href="https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca/wood-flooring/hardwood.html" class="ma_level_2 ma_item "><i class="fto-angle-right list_arrow"></i>Hardwood Flooring</a>
               </li>

            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="ml_level_1">
            <a id="st_ma_19" href="https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca/vinyl-flooring.html"  class="ma_level_1 ma_item  has_children "><i class="fto-angle-right list_arrow"></i>Vinyl Flooring<span class="is_parent_icon"><b class="is_parent_icon_h"></b><b class="is_parent_icon_v"></b></span></a>        
            <ul class="mu_level_2 p_granditem_1">
               <li class="ml_level_2 granditem_0 p_granditem_1">
                  <a href="https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca/vinyl-flooring/vinyl-plank.html" class="ma_level_2 ma_item "><i class="fto-angle-right list_arrow"></i>Vinyl Plank</a>
               </li>
               <li class="ml_level_2 granditem_0 p_granditem_1">
                  <a href="https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca/vinyl-flooring/vinyl-tile.html"  class="ma_level_2 ma_item "><i class="fto-angle-right list_arrow"></i>Vinyl Tile</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="ml_level_1"><a id="st_ma_20" href="https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca/carpets.html"  class="ma_level_1 ma_item "><i class="fto-angle-right list_arrow"></i>Carpet Flooring</a></li>
         <li class="ml_level_1"><a id="st_ma_21" href="https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca/speciality-flooring.html"  class="ma_level_1 ma_item "><i class="fto-angle-right list_arrow"></i>Speciality Flooring</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add `current` class to the current active page.

I have written the following jquery, but it is not working.

```
$('#st_mega_menu_wrap').find('li').click(function(){
       $('#st_mega_menu_wrap').find('li.current').removeClass('current');
        if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('stmenu_multi_level')){
             $(this).parents('li').addClass('current');
        }else{
             $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });
```

How can i make it working properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the class `current` to the currently active page, you can check in a `$(document).ready(function(){})` on page load which `<a>` tag has the value of the current URL as `href` attribute and set the class `current` to its parent `<li>`:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    let url = window.location.href;
    let current = $(".stmenu_multi_level").find("a[href='" + url + "']");
    current.closest("li").addClass("current");
 });
```

Comment: Its not adding any class to any level of the menu

Comment: @MuntashirAreRahi That's strange as it's working in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6udm9bft/2/

Comment: try to run your code in some other browser as @matthias_h has written the right answer.

Comment: mm. Still no luck. Here is my site. Can you please check source on this site? https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca

Comment: @MuntashirAreRahi When I e.g. go to this page https://www.thehardwoodoutlet.ca/wood-flooring.html the <li> of the <a> with the right href gets the class "current" which seems not to be defined. Also works on other pages. On which page does it not work?